# Interface or type with object as key in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have an object with a series of values:

```
const my_enum = {
    value1: 'x-value-1',
    value2: 'x-value-2'

}
```

I want to use 'x-value-1' and 'x-value-2' as the keys of a interface or a type, something like

```
interface my_interface {
    'x-value-1': string;
    'x-value-2': string;
}
```

However, I don't want to use my enum to determine the keys, so I can use them on the rest of the code, and if I ever want to change my keys I don't need to worry about my strings all over the place. Is there a way to do something like the following?

```
interface my_interface {
    `${value1}`: string;
    `${value2}`: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
const TextType = "Text"; // or "Message" etc
const TitleType = "Title";
const PriorityType = "Priority";

type Notification {
    [TextType]?: string
    [TitleType]?: string
    [PriorityType]?: number
}
```